# How does one invoke the same claim rules from ADFS on all registered relying parties?

Tags: active-directory, identity, wif, adfs, claims

My company is getting into ADFS and WIF to set up an internal portal with SSO capabilities. We currently have custom rules that build additional claims from a SQL attribute store based on the user's active directory group(s).

In a couple of years, there may be upwards of 30-40 applications hooked into the portal. For maintainability purposes, we want to change these base rules, that will apply to all of these apps, in one place. We want to avoid having to set up the custom rules on each relying party entry in ADFS.

Also, SharePoint is not an option for the portal.

Can anyone give advice on the best way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AD FS 2.0 Cmdlets in Windows PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee892329.aspx).

There's an example here: [AD FS 2.0: How to Bulk Add Trust Relationships and Claim Rules for Testing](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4566.ad-fs-2-0-how-to-bulk-add-trust-relationships-and-claim-rules-for-testing-en-us.aspx)